# how to create spin the wheel godot

Tags: godot

I want to create a 2d board game that involve a spinning wheel that has 1 - 6 numbers that pick in random then it will animate in the wheel. how can i code the physics of a spinning wheel while generating an random number 1 - 6??

Comment: i want physics based wheel simulation to pick a random 1 to 6 number then use the wheel spinning animation to show it by user push button i was struggling with the physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a physics simulation, in 2D, in Godot, for a wheel spinning...

We will make the wheel as a `RigidBody2D`. It will have a a `Sprite` child for visual representation.

A couple options for fixing it in place come to mind:

- You can set its `gravity_scale` to `0`, so it does not fall. *In theory something else could knock it off.*
- You can use a `PinJoint2D` to fix  it an `StaticBody2D`. *Make sure the `PinJoint2D` has `Node A` and `Node B` connected to the `StaticBody2D` and `RigidBody2D`.*

I'll also suggest to have a `Node2D` to contain the whole arrangement (that way you can position the parent `Node2D` instead of moving its children nodes). It is also convenient to put our code there, in particular if we want to save this as a scene and instance it somewhere else.

*`CollisionShape`s are NOT strictly necessary in this case, but you may add them too.*

---

For the rotation the simplest solution is to give it a random `angular_velocity`.

I'll be writing the code for the parent `Node2D`. For example:

```
func spin() -> void:
    $RigidBody2D.angular_velocity = rand_range(500.0, 10000.0)
```

And it will slow down and stop according to its `angular_damp`.

---

We also need to know when it stopped. For that we can add a custom signal:

```
signal stopped_spinning
```

And check the angular velocity in `_physics_process` to know when it stopped.

By the way, we cannot rely on the angular velocity hitting 0. Instead we will consider it stopped when it is close to zero.

I will take advantage of `set_physics_process` to enable when spinning, and disable it is when done:

```
extends Node2D

signal stopped_spinning

func _ready() -> void:
    set_physics_process(false)

func spin() -> void:
    $RigidBody2D.angular_velocity = rand_range(500.0, 10000.0)
    set_physics_process(true)
    
func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if abs($RigidBody2D.angular_velocity) < 0.02:
        $RigidBody2D.angular_velocity = 0.0
        emit_signal("stopped_spinning")
        set_physics_process(false)
```

*In my test, the angular velocity gets down to `0.010584`. So I picked `0.02` as threshold. If that gives you problems, experiment with the value.*

*Even though I only put positive angular velocities, I decided to use `abs` so the code can handle a negative value.*

---

You can then create a button, and make it call `spin` when pressed. You can also handle the custom `"stopped_spinning"` signal to get the result. For that, you may use `$RigidBody2D.rotation_degrees` and some arithmetic, for example:

```
func get_value() -> int:
    var offset_degrees = 90
    var options = 6
    var option_degrees = 360 / options
    return int(fposmod($RigidBody2D.rotation_degrees + offset_degrees, 360) / option_degrees) + 1
```

The `fposmod` will give you a value between 0 and the second parameter (360 in this case).

*I added `offset_degrees` to account for the fact that I don't know at what angle the first option is. Also, I added 1 at the end because it would give you values in the range [0, options), but you probably want a value on the range [1, options]. Tweak that as needed.*